# When Lulu's shield is on a teammate, who do Pix's bolts count for?

Tags: league-of-legends

When a Lulu puts her shield (`E`) on a teammate, every time they auto-attack Pix also fires a bolt.  Does this bolt "count" for Lulu or that character?

For example, let's say your AD carry is trying to get red buff.  You, as Lulu, put your shield on them.  Now every time the AD carry auto-attacks, there is a Pix bolt added to it.  If it just so happens that the damage from Pix's bolt is what kills the Elder Lizard, will Lulu end up with the buff?  Or will the AD carry still get it?

The same question could be asked for champion kills.

If it counts for Lulu, this seems like a big hazard as a support character.

Comment: Damage and kills counts for the one it is on. It's considered a buff, and buffs doesn't steal kills.

Comment: @Wertilq - it's a special kind of buff, as it associates a "pet" to another character. It's not a direct attack buff. And on release, there were issues with it attributing some kills to Lulu when it shouldn't have been. It's all good now, though.

Comment: +1 good question, I never really thought about or considered this. Nice to know!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "attack buff" that Lulu grants is just what it is - an attack buff. The carry's attack that is enhanced by Pix's bolt is still an attack caused by the carry. Basically, when the carry kills someone with Lulu's buff, **it's still the carry that kills** that target, and is the carry that is **accounted for the kill**.

Comment: this is correct in my experience, playing as caitlyn i have several times had a lulu on my team supporting me in bot lane. whenever pix was on me and i auto attacked, pix would attack as well and often would kill the minion i was attacking when i misjudged my last hit, i still received the gold and credit for the minion kill.

Comment: Yes, it's like this indeed, at least since they fixed the behavior.  On Lulu's release, Pix's bolts at the end of the buff (when he was coming back to Lulu) were incorrectly counted as Lulu's attacks. This lead to a LOT of argues between ADC and Lulu's, as you can expect, since it was leading to kill steals, and buff steals from the support.

Comment: @Gnoupi Thanks for your follow-up comments explaining the history of this feature/bug as well.

Comment: @Jeff You almost sound as if you work at Microsoft.

Comment: @user1337 Haha, I actually am a software developer, but not for Microsoft.  Why do you say that out of curiosity?

Comment: @Jeff "It's not a bug. It's a feature". I'm pretty sure that quote originated somewhere at Microsoft.

Comment: @Jeff upvoted for the laugh XD